# How to get custom exception details out of a sys.exc_info?

Tags: python

I want to consolidate some exception handling code into a single exception clause but I'm having difficulty with getting all the exception info I need since exc_info is missing info.

```
import sys

class CustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, custom_code):
        Exception.__init__(self)
        self.custom_code = custom_code

try:
        raise CustomException("test")
# This is OK
# except CustomException as ex:
#       print "Caught CustomException, custom_code=" + ex.custom_code
# But I want to be able to have a single except clause...
except:
        ex = sys.exc_info()[0]
        if ex is CustomException:
                # AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'custom_code'
                print "Caught CustomException, custom_code=" + ex.custom_code
```

The overall idea is that the code in the except clause can be put in a function that anyone can call just by catching except. I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: Why do you want to have a single `except` clause if you want to be able to handle different exception types differently?  If you want an `except` block to handle several types the same you can do `except (CustomException, IOError, KeyError) as ex:` or whatever list of exception types you want

Comment: I want other people to be able to have a single except clause and call my error handler that handles everything. except: dealWithIt().

Comment: The object is in `sys.exc_info()[1]`.

Comment: This is generally bad practice because it will ignore other types of exceptions that you didn't anticipate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the error you says your code produce.

Apart thinking that recommending to use `except:dealwithIt()` is a terrible idea for the reason it will shadow exception, here is the code which I think does what you want.

```
import sys

class CustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, custom_code):
        Exception.__init__(self)
        self.custom_code = custom_code

try:
        raise CustomException("test")

except:
        ex_value = sys.exc_info()[1]
        if isinstance(ex_value,CustomException):
                print "Caught CustomException, custom_code=" + ex_value.custom_code
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for. I don't think it's a terrible idea. If you have a bunch of methods doing something that could generate different errors that should be handled with some extra common code plus need to catch everything then this avoids a lot of code duplication (that people probably won't actually write for error handling). For example in my case I want to always return a JSON HTTP response for some functions if anything goes wrong.

Comment: You can have the exact same behavior by explicitly catching your `CustomException` and `Exception` (not bare `except` as it also catch `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit` that you certainly don't want) and maybe factor out common code in some function

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need.

```
import sys

class CustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, custom_code):
        Exception.__init__(self)
        self.custom_code = custom_code

try:
    raise CustomException("test")

except Exception as e:
    ex = sys.exc_info()[0]
    if ex is CustomException:
            # AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'custom_code'
            print "Caught CustomException, custom_code=" + e.custom_code
```

`ex = sys.exc_info()[0]` in this case `ex` refers to the class `CustomException` as the exception type rather than an instance of the exception.